# Composer unsatisfied requirement

Tags: composer-php, satis

In a composer setup I need `vendor/package-A` and `vendor/package-B`.

Package B builds upon package A and has A defined as a requirement in its composer.json.

Directly installing the base package A works fine. Other requirements are resolved from Packagist and the package itself is correctly pulled from the private repository.

However, when installing only package B (which should then also pull in package A due to the requirement), I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
  - Installation request for vendor/package-B dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by vendor/package-B[dev-master].
  - vendor/package-B dev-master requires vendor/package-A dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.
```

Both packages don't have any tagged releases and operate at the dev-master version.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

---

**EDIT**

For those interested in the solution, this is a summary from what I've learned from the selected answer below.

Basically, three methods exist to get deep dev-master dependencies installed. In order of most recommended:

1. Tag all releases and use tagged version constraints instead of dev-master everywhere. *(I actually ended up doing this!)*
2. In your application's `composer.json`, add an additional require key using the `@dev` flag for the corresponding subdepencency you need in dev:

   ```
   {
       "require": {
           "vendor/package-B": "dev-master",
           "vendor/package-A": "@dev"
       }
   }
   ```

   This way you basically whitelist a specific subdependency to be used as dev.
3. In your application's `composer.json`, add the `minimum-stability` and `prefer-stable` keys as follows.

   ```
   {
       "minimum-stability": "dev",
       "prefer-stable" : true
   }
   ```

   In this last method you lower the stability constraint to be dev, but you also set that IF a stable version is available, you'll prefer that one instead. Most of the time this would generate the wanted behavior, but sometimes it can be quirky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a stability resolution problem.

The best solution for this situation is to **start tagging your releases**.

You might define `"minmum-stability":"dev"`.

It will set the lower bound and allow "dev" packages for all packages.

You have explicitly defined `dev-master@dev`.
I'm not sure that this is really needed.

This explains your situation: https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html

Comment: What a wonderfully informative website; I didn't know about the root-stability definition. Thanks once again!